# Deviation analysis color to vertex color using Meshlab

Tags: colors, analysis, vertex, measurement

I would to know if is possible to do deviation analysis with Meshlab and transfer the result to vertex color in a mesh. So expand those 2 ideas...

1st. Is it possible to do deviation analysis with MeshLab? I have a scanned mesh and I will compare with a "ideal model". The difference between these 2 will generate a (grey or color) scale information that represent the distance I have from the points of the scanned model to the "ideal" one.

2nd. I want to get this information (color/grey grading that shows how distant the points are) and transfer to a vertex color information. 
I don't know it was clear, but if you know what deviation analysis means I think you got it. The difference is that I would like the generate a 3d mesh with the vertex color provided by this deviation analysis.

Seems that mesh lab can compare two models and can deal with vertex colorizing, but I don't Know if is possible to deal with real measurements, transfer this information to vertex color and export a mesh that show it.

If its possible and If you know how just point me some direction. I'm not familiar with Meshlab and click here and there trying a impossible task can be very frustrating, so it will be good if someone can give me some tips.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, MeshLab can compute deviation analysis between two similar surfaces (and the required alignment preprocessing too).

Estimating the deviation between two meshes means computing the hausdorff distance.
There is a small tutorial on how to compute and visualize it in MeshLab here:

http://meshlabstuff.blogspot.com/2010/01/measuring-difference-between-two-meshes.html